# How to monitor Elasticache metrics for Redis like resources used

Tags: redis, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elasticache

I want to monitor the metrics for Redis like memory.
Can anyone tell how to find these metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is done through the AWS console, for memory usage you can use the`BytesUsedForCache`metric. For other metrics refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/CacheMetrics.Redis.html

Comment: login to cloudwatch: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home, under "Metrics" click on ElastiCache, click on "BytesUsedForCache" on the right side, under "CacheClusterId" place a checkmark next to the Cache cluster you want to monitor. The graph will appear at the bottom and from there you can add it to a dashboard for quicker access the next time.